# What might happen if I use FTP client without TLS?

Tags: https, security, ftp

For some reason connecting to server using FTP client (eg. filezilla) is not working with TLS encryption enabled. I had to disable it to use FTP. So wondering why is TLS needed in the first place and what are the risks I am having by disabling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Source: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/477/20604
>
> It's important to keep a few things in mind when using FTP - it is not
>   encrypted by default meaning your credentials and content that you
>   send are sent in the clear so are vulnerable to interception. To
>   address this you should connect to your hosting provider using FTPS
>   (FTP over SSL/TLS).

---

> Source: [SFTP, FTPS and SecureFTP differences and security implications](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/870)
>
> There are 3 different protocols commonly used for transfering files over the Internet, and they are commonly confused between.
>
> - [FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) - an extension to the FTP protocol to support using FTP over SSL/TLS. This is typically based on a client-requested negotiation, and there are specific FTP commands to request/enforce/implement the encryption using SSL.
> - [FTP over SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#FTP_over_SSH_.28not_SFTP.29) (commonly called SecureFTP) - tunneling standard FTP over a SSH connection. Take into account that it is a bit more complicated to force the data channels to continue tunneling over SSH, even if the control channel is tunnelled.
> - [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol) - This is a completely *different* protocol, SSH File Transfer Protocol. *This is **not** related to FTP, but is a completely different protocol.* SFTP is actually a sub-protocol from the SSH protocol suite, i.e. a SSH extension (however I understand that it *can* be used seperately, too).
>
> Advantage of FTPS is that it is similar to HTTPS - same type of certificate, etc. Many webservers support FTPS natively, and thus it is often "simpler" to set up and have admins up to speed faster.
>   SFTP has advantage in *nix shops, that are typically already more SSH-friendly - if they already set up a public SSH server securely, its pretty simple to add SFTP functionality.
>
> Note that SecureFTP (FTP over SSH) is NOT trivial in any case (even if you already have the SSH set up), and I haven't seen it in use by security-conscious orgs (that's not to say it CAN'T be, but isn't commonly).

Comment: what you mean my credentials? it is too risky! and who can do this interception? what are the tools needed?

Comment: Can be intercepted various ways from sniffing packets. You're need to Google it because its far to much to explain in an answer never mind a comment field. Your best of fixing the issue and using SFTP for security reasons... Band aids will only work for so long.

Comment: I have talked with the hosting site, they say they are ok with TLS, then I think it is my ISP that is blocking TLS

Comment: I've added abit more information about the various of types of FTP for you.